# Symfony template does not render labels in EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

Instead of interpreting things like `{{ list.page_title }}`, it's just rendering as `list.page_title`, `paginator.next`, `action.search`, etc. I'm not getting any errors in the debug toolbar or dev log. I have cleared the cache.

[image: EasyAdmin page]

Is there some setting I missed? How do I fix this or figure out where the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the translator service is enabled in config.yml

```
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: [ "en" ] }
```

For more translation customisation see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/tutorials/i18n.html